C# Supabase implementation (Unity) Problem
I'm encountering reference errors in my Unity code while attempting to utilize Supabase classes for interacting with a PostgreSQL database. Although all dependencies seem to be correctly imported and configured, I'm encountering errors such as 'Reference to type 'BaseModel' claims it is defined in 'Supabase.Postgrest', but it could not be found' and 'The type 'gerencia' cannot be used as type parameter 'TModel' in the generic type or method 'Client.From()''. Could someone provide insights into what might be causing these issues?
I have 2 class.. "gerencia" y "Consultas"...
using Supabase.Postgrest.Models;
using Supabase.Postgrest.Attributes;
using Supabase;
using Supabase.Interfaces;
using Supabase.Postgrest;
using Supabase.Postgrest.Models;

public class gerencia : BaseModel
{
    [Column("id"), PrimaryKey]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Column("nombre")]
    public string nombre { get; set; }
}

using UnityEngine;
using Supabase;
using Supabase.Interfaces;
using Supabase.Postgrest;
using Supabase.Postgrest.Models;
using Supabase.Postgrest.Attributes;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TMPro;

public class Consultas : MonoBehaviour
{
    string supabaseUrl = //url hidden//;
    string supabaseKey = //key hidden//;

    Supabase.Client clientSupabase;

    // UI Elements
    [SerializeField] TMP_Text resultadosText;

    async void Start()
    {
        clientSupabase = new Supabase.Client(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey);

        var response = await clientSupabase
            .From<gerencia>()
            .Select("*")
            .Get();
    }
}

The error occurs at .From().Select("*"). I understand the nature of the error, but I'm unsure how to resolve it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!
I attempted to utilize the Supabase library in Unity to interact with a PostgreSQL database. Specifically, I created two classes: "gerencia" and "Consultas". In the "Consultas" class, I instantiated a Supabase client and attempted to retrieve data using the .From().Select("*") method chain.
I expected this code to compile successfully and retrieve data from the "gerencia" table in my Supabase database. Despite ensuring that all dependencies are properly imported and configured, these errors persist.
